# Problems accessing multiple docker containers remotely

Tags: docker

I'm trying to set up some docker container demo blogs but I'm having problems when I try to access more than one:

```
docker run --volumes-from my-data -p 80:8080 --name site1 tutum/wordpress
docker run --volumes-from my-data -p 80:8081 --name site2 tutum/wordpress
```

I can access the first one from myhost:8080 but I can't access the second one from myhost:8081
Is there anything obvious I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The `-p` argument tells docker how to map external addresses to internal (container) addresses. You are instructing it to map port 80 of all host interfaces to port 8080/8081 of the respective container. Assuming the container processes really  listen on port 8080/8081 you might want to try `-p 8080:8080` / `-p8081:8081`. If the containers run standard webservers  on port 80, you might want to use `-p 8080:80` / `-p 8081:80` instead. The proper port  mapping will make the container service accessible on port  8080/8081 of all host interfaces.

Comment: I really just want it to listen on any available port and be able to reverse proxy to it from apache on the host.

Comment: tutum/wordpress listens (internally) on port 80. Try -p8080:80 and reverse proxy to port 8080 on any interface of the host.  127.0.0.1:8080 should be fine and reach the service running in the container.